# How can I find out if two parabolas will share an integer in their sequence?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

I have two parabolas:

$x = 4y^2 + 48y + 24$

$x = 4y^2 + 4y$

When I graph $4y^2+4y$ it hits the number $x=24$ at $y = -3$ and $y = 2$

When I graph

$4y^2 + 48y + 24$
it hits $x = 24$ at $y = -12$ and $y = 0$

I'd like to be able to tell no matter what the two parabola equations are if they will share a common integer. And where the first common integer hits. But these porabolas may not necessarily intersect but still share a common x value like 24.

It might be very similar to these:
[How to find the meeting number of two sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147152/how-to-find-the-meeting-number-of-two-sequences)
[How can I find a common factor of two polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060453/how-can-i-find-a-common-factor-of-two-polynomials?rq=1)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Or this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

But I can't seem to plug it in.

Do I set them equal like this and solve for y?
$4y^2+48y+24 = 4y^2+4y$

Do I set them equal but with a different variable and solve for each?
$4y^2+48y+24 = 4x^2+4x$

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/588038).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I _think_ you are looking for not one integer $y$ but two, say $y_1$ and $y_2$, for which $$4y_1^2+48y_1+24 = 4y_2^2 +4y_2.$$

Comment: MJD I think that is correct. So those two formulas have a sequence of numbers like
n1,n2,..24..nx
and
n1,24, n3...nx

They share the 24 so I would want to know the first sequence it appears at location of 3, and the second one it appears at location 2.
But also a way to say 'yes they will have a common term' without cycling through possibly a million numbers first.

Comment: I'm thinking of going over what I know.

Comment: I'm guessing you want only for integer inputs ?

Comment: Taking the so-called "canonical form" of your two quadratics will simplify your issue !

Comment: Parabolas are continuous functions - One should not think of them as discrete sequence of values. Whd user MJD suggested should be good enough.

Comment: I am not sure how to take MJDs solution and get it to tell me this:
$$
4(0)^2+48(0)+24=4(2)^2+4(2).
$$
where Y1 would come back as 0 and Y2 is 2 where that is the first spot in each sequence where a similar integer appears (24).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve $4y_1^2+48y_1+24 = 4y_2^2+4y_2$ for integer solutions.  This can be rewritten as:
$4(y_1+6)^2-(2y_2+1)^2=119$ or $(2y_1+2y_2+13)(2y_1-2y_2+11)=119$

All possible solutions now must be from one of the allowable factorisations: 
$119 = 1\times 119 = 7\times 17$, where ordering and $\pm1$ could be used to generate more cases.  From these eight cases, we get all the solutions $(y_1, y_2) \in \{ (24, -30), (-36, 29), (24, 29), (-36, -30), (0, -3), (-12, 2), (0, 2), (-12, -3)\}$

Comment: Hi Macavity,
It sounds like your solution is what I am looking for.
But now I am trying to figure out how you start here:
$$
4y_1^2+48y_1+24 = 4y_2^2+4y_2
$$

And get to here:

$$
4(y_1+6)^2-(2y_2+1)^2=119
$$

When I start to factor the equation I get this:
$$
4(y_1+12y_1+6) = 4y_2(y_2+1)
$$

But what would be the next step.
Also, I am not sure where 119 came from to set it equal to that?

Actually it looks like you solve for dy/dx, then did 

$$
dx^2 - dy^2 = n^2
$$

So I think my only question now is where did 119 come from?

Comment: @MathBabylon I “completed the square” on both sides, what is left is $119$. Then one can factor the form $a^2-b^2$ to get the above results.

Answer (score 1):

A little help:

In the case of integer inputs, coefficient gcd helps in the above case; they both produce only multiples of 4. We can then ask if $y^2+12y+6$ and $y^2+y$ can both be 6. If not, we can give up on the originals ever being 24. You can check for divisibility by its divisors first, starting with prime divisors, continuing with prime powers; if it fails for any of them, or has contradicting conditions on them, then it fails.

Parity arguments and modular arithmetic come in handy here. Via parity arguments, we can show that if a polynomial is odd or even depends on the parity, of the cardinality, of the set of its odd coefficients; if even in number, parity falls to the constant term. Otherwise, parity is opposite the constant term on odd inputs, and the same parity as the constant only at even inputs. This immediately says for example, that $3x^2+5x+7$ and either one above will never both be the same number with integer inputs and outputs; one is always odd, and one is always even.

Polynomial remainder theorem can be used for algebraic a values; it still involves testing the first certain number of values though.

Chinese remainder theorem allows you to find out that if the polynomial is only divisible by 5 at inputs that have remainder 4 on division by 5, and divisible by 7 at inputs with remainder on division by 7 of 6, that divisibility by 35 or its multiples only comes up at inputs that are remainder 34 on division by 35.

Comment: I was hoping to confirm if the 2 equations should share an integer value in their sequence, in this case I already know its true where:
$$
4(0)2+48(0)+24=4(2)2+4(2).
$$

I am not sure how to take what you said above and prove this to be the case, without plugging on 0,1,2,3,4 into each function and comparing to each possible output of the second function.

Comment: It looks like when I have:
$$
x=4a^2+48a+24
$$
$$
x=4b^2+4b
$$
I can simplify the second into
$$
x=4b(b+1)
$$

Then I can say
$$
4a^2+48a+24 = 4b(b+1)
$$
Which becomes
$$
((4a^2+48a+24)/4b) - b = 1
$$

Then if I graph that I can see it hits a non decimal at (2,0), (-3,0)  (2,-12), (-3,-12). 
So I guess that partially answers my question. But I was hoping to be able to get those points without plugging into an equation until non-decimals appeared and somehow calculate them.

Comment: first one of the reduced hits 6 at 0, second hits 6 at 2, that simple.